# jQuery checkbox change doesnt trigger properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide/show elements based on a checkbox change event. The event does get triggered, but the hide/show isn't working.

This is my code:

```
$("#inlineCheckbox3").change(function() {   
    $checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    console.log($checked); //logs true or false properly
    if (!$checked) {
        $("#myDiv").hide(); //this doesnt work at all.
        alert('test'); //alert is working
    }
});
```

If I put something like:

```
if ($("#inlineCheckbox3").is(":checked")) {
    $("#myDiv").hide();
}
```

it does work on my console.

---

Solution:

There was a second `.click()` handler in my JavaScript that caused the div to be hidden reappear right away. This way it seemed like it didnt get hidden.

Comment: Share the HTML code and Script in JSFiddle Or there is a functionality here on stackoverflow. It is always helpful and easier to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: So if the alert is working, this has nothing to do with the checkbox changed event. By "doesn't work at all" do you mean `#myDiv` doesn't get hidden?

Comment: please also provide the needed html markup, best in form of a jsfiddle or the functionality here on stackoverflow

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas: Ideally not a fiddle, but rather a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) right here on site.

Comment: Definitely will need the HMTL, as that's likely the issue.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. Please don't ask-and-run. *Stick around* to answer questions such as the ones above.

Answer (score 4):

Try this (`Run CODE Snippet` & check / uncheck the checkbox):

```js
(function($){
  $("#inlineCheckbox3").change(function() {   
    $checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    if (!$checked) {
        $("#myDiv").hide();
    }
    else {
      $("#myDiv").show();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inlineCheckbox3" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

## What I did differently:

1. In your CODE you only added `hide()` function, didn't `show()` it back again when checkbox was checked.
2. Depending on the scope, you'll not always be able to access `$`. That's why I wrapped my CODE with `(function($){})(jQuery);`

Most likely you were getting error in one of these two.